# Autocommit ODBC api not working through IBM iAccess to unixODBC to ruby-odbc

Tags: ruby, odbc, ibm-midrange

I am currently using ODBC to access an IBM as400 machine through Rails -> (small as400 odbc adapter) -> odbc_adapter (gem 4.2.4) -> ruby-odbc (gem 0.999991) -> unixODBC (2.3.4, ubuntu 18.04) -> IBMiAccess (latest).  By some miracle, this all works pretty well, except for recently we were having problems with strings containing specific characters causing an error to be raised in ruby-odbc.

Retrieving a record with the special character '¬' fails with:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (ArgumentError: negative string size (or size too big): SELECT * from data WHERE id = 4220130.0)
```

Seems the special character ends up taking up 2 bytes and whatever conversions are happening don't handle this correctly.

Strings without special characters are being returned with encoding Encoding:ASCII-8BIT.

There is a utf8 version of ruby-odbc, which I was able to load by requiring it in our iSeries adapter, and then requiring odbc_adapter:

```
require 'odbc_utf8'  # force odbc_adapter to use the utf8 version
require 'odbc_adapter'
```

This allows the utf8 version of odbc-ruby to occupy the ODBC module name, which the odbc_adapter will just use.  Though there was a problem:

`odbc_adapter` calls `.get_info` for a number of fields on `raw_connection` (odbc-ruby), and these strings come back wrong, for example the string `"DB2/400 SQL"` which is from ODBC::SQL_DBMS_NAME looks like:  `"D\x00B\x002\x00/\x004\x000\x000\x00 \x00S\x00Q\x00L\x00"`, with an encoding of `Encoding:ASCII-8BIT`. `odbc_adapter` uses a regex to map dbms to our adapter, which doesn't match:  `/DB2\/400 SQL/ =~ (this_string)` => `null`.

I'm not super familiar with string encodings, but was able to hack in a `.gsub("\0", "")` here to fix this detection.  After this, I can return records with special characters in their strings.  They are returned without error, with visible special characters in `Encoding:UTF-8`.

Of course, now querying on special characters fails:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (ODBC::Error: HY001 (30027) [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Memory allocation error.: SELECT * from data WHERE (mystring like '%¬%'))
```

but I'm not too concerned with that.  The problem now is that it seems the UTF8 version of ruby-odbc sets the ODBC version to 3, where on the non-utf8 version it was 2:

```
Base.connection.raw_connection.odbc_version => 3
```

And this seems to prevent autocommit from working (works on version 2):

```
Base.connection.raw_connection.autocommit => true
Base.connection.raw_connection.autocommit = false 
ODBC::Error (IM001 (0) [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver does not support this function)
```

This function is used to start/end transactions in the odbc_adapter, and seems to be a standard feature of odbc:
https://github.com/localytics/odbc_adapter/blob/master/lib/odbc_adapter/database_statements.rb#L51

I poked around in the IBMiAccess documentation, and found something about transaction levels and a new "trueautocommit" option, but I can't seem to figure out if this trueautocommit replaces autocommit, or even if autocommit is no longer supported in this way.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-odbc-commit-mode-data-source-setting-isolation-level-and-autocommit

Of course I have no idea of how to set this new 'trueautocommit' connection setting via the ruby-odbc gem.  It does support `.set_option` on the raw_connection, so I can call something like `.set_option(ODBC::SQL_AUTOCOMMIT, false)`, which fails in exactly the same way. `ODBC::SQL_AUTOCOMMIT` is just a constant for `102`, which I've found referenced in a few places regarding ODBC, so I figure if I could figure out the constant for `TRUEAUTOCOMMIT`, I might be able to set it in this way, but can't find any documentation for this.

Any advice for getting `.autocommit` working in this configuration?

Edit: Apparently you can use a DSN for odbc, so I've also tried creating one in /etc/odbc.ini, along with the option for "TrueAutoCommit = 1" but this hasn't changed anything as far as getting .autocommit to work.